# Knife crime in the UK/London

Tags: data-request, geospatial, crime

Knife crime is a big issue in London. The recent terrorist attack on Tower bridge is another dramatic example. I'm looking for open data on the location of these crimes in London or the UK. I don't know if that can be on any help Understanding the phenomenon.

- I've looked on https://data.police.uk/data/ but the categories is not accurate enough. Knife crime falls into the category `Violence and sexual offences`.
- I've also looked at the office of national statistics website which as [a page dedicated on it](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/crimeandjustice/bulletins/crimeinenglandandwales/yearendingjune2019#rise-in-offences-involving-knives-or-sharp-instruments-and-firearms-offences), but it rather looks like a sum up.